# How do I create .iso file with all installed software in ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to make **.iso** file with all installed software in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS, so that I can install ubuntu in my friends laptop , and get the same thing as in my laptop. Can it be done by systemback ? If yes, please give me full details . thanks.

Comment: Posted new answer, more info if you want it ;)

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to make an iso to install the same packages.
you can list your packages and install them on the laptop after you installed ubuntu.
see third answer on:
[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

i guess you can try using systemback to create an iso of your system but you will still need to install ubuntu and systemback to restore. i have no idea if that will work, interested to see if its possible without too many errors/problems.
http://www.unixmen.com/systemback-restore-linux-system-previous-state/

Comment: Is  **Internet Connection**  is necessary  in both of there cases to **restore** this software to **New** computer ?

Answer (score 1):

This tool is maybe helps you: http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note I have used part of your answer in mine below as an attempt to consolidate link answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remastersys can help you make custom iso files

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remastersys.html

Comment: Note I have used part of your answer in mine below as an attempt to consolidate link answers.

Answer (score 1):

From the answers above, I thought I would condense them into one, without using links (hmph). First, you can use [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/). This is an Ubuntu based software that you can install. With this software you can do the following:

- Backup
- Transport
- Download
- And share what you backup

The link above will have the download link, but else do the following in terminal after downloading the tar.gz:

```
$ tar -xvzf /path/to/download/aptoncd-*.tar.gz
$ cd aptoncd/
$ sudo make install
```

The next is [Remastersys](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remastersys.html).

By default, Remastersys is not listed in the official Ubuntu repositories. We need add it. To add a source, click System > Administration > Software Sources. This will bring up a menu of all currently used sources that Synaptic (the package manager) refers to when searching for new installations and updates. Click on the Third-Party Software tab for more details.
Next, click Add. This will open another window, where you need to input the new source address. The address that we require is:

```
deb http://www.remastersys.klikit-linux.com/repository remastersys/
```

Remastersys add sources 2

After you have added the new repository, power up Synaptic, look for Remastersys and install it. Now, start Remastersys. The GUI can be accessed via System > Administration > Remastersys Backup. You have several options to choose from:

> Backup allows you to backup your entire installation, along with all the personal data and configurations.

Next is Dist

> Dist allows you to create a backup, sans your personal data, allowing you to share the "remastered" copy with other people.

Next is Modify

> Modify is useful for configuring the name and the location of the backup file, as well as some other settings. You can also manually edit and change the configurations file - /etc/remastersys.conf. It is advisable to backup the file before making any changes.

Finally is clean

> Clean is useful only after you have used Remastersys at least once. This function will remove previous builds made by the program and free up the hard disk space. You can also do this manually if you wish. It is always a good idea to run the Clean option before running a new backup.

We will begin with editing the options, perform a cleanup second and then run the backup. If you're using the software the first time, the cleanup is not necessary. However, you should revise the backup options. This is not strictly necessary, but might be important if you are low on disk space.
do a  `Clean`. This should take a few moments. Then do a `Backup`. Now comes the really interesting part. Please note that you must close all windows and unmount network shares while running the utility. The GUI will even throw up a warning to inform you about this. If you do not do this, it is possible that your backup could fail. Once you have unmounted network shares and closed all windows, click OK to proceed. The backup will begin. Depending on the size of your distro, this could take some time.After the backup is done, you should burn the created image file (ISO) and test it. Indeed, this is our next step. Then, boot your custom iso in [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Notice the splash screen is different from the typical Ubuntu logo. Furthermore, notice the surrounding window frame, which belongs to VirtualBox. Indeed, as advised by the backup GUI, we're testing the custom.iso file in a virtual machine, to ensure that it works as desired, and it does. Remastersys is a very handsome application. In a way, it is an on-the-fly imaging software. But it also allows you to boot your image as a live CD, reinstall it on another machine - or give it out to friends (if you have any), as a ready-to-use Linux, with every little hack and trick you like already implemented. Remastersys is powerful - and simple. There's no need to mess up with the command line or figure out what partitions you want to backup and whether they are mounted or not. For most people, the use of Remastersys will be a simple affair, just a few mouse clicks and you're done.